# Degree of field extensions $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(\alpha^{12})/\mathbb Q$, where $\alpha = 2^{1/3}+3^{1/4}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

How do I find the degree of the following field extensions $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(\alpha^{12})/\mathbb Q$, where $\alpha = 2^{1/3}+3^{1/4}$ ?

Note : Since $\mathbb Q(\alpha) \subseteq \mathbb Q(2^{1/3},3^{1/4})$ and $[\mathbb Q(2^{1/3},3^{1/4}):\mathbb Q]=12$, so $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]|12$ ; but then I have no clue how to proceed further.

Please help.

Comment: Have you think about [Q(2^(1/3)),Q] and Q[(3^(1/4),Q]?